# Как ратянуть элементы внутри контрола?

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

На главной форме есть элемент panel в нее подгружается "пользовательский элемент управления", при развертывании окна на весь экран элементы внутри контрола не растягиваются.

Вот фрагмент кода где происходит подключение контрола:

```
private void kontr_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   kontr_control kontr = new kontr_control();
   content.Controls.Clear();
   content.Controls.Add(kontr);
}
```

как растянуть элементы внутри дочернего контрола при развертывания окна?

Comment: Anchors заюзай, если это WinForms

Comment: везде уже выставлены, но не помогает

Answer (score 1):

`kontr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` растягивает контрол на всю доступную площадь родителя

Comment: спасибо, помогло